# Looking for a transparent conductive spray/paint/ink

Tags: capacitance, capacitive, conductive

I know there are conductive sprays available, but these are strongly coloured due to the metals inside them. I am trying to make a (dry) wooden surface capacitive, but would like to have the feel and look of the wood remain intact. Therefore I would like a spray/paint/ink that is transparent and conductive and preferably also water-resistant.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

P.S. I'm using it to measure capacitance all across the wood (which is 1.5m in length) so the resistance per cm^3 doesn't matter. It could have a nice effect if the capacitance differential is significantly different at various distances from the point I measure.

Comment: http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/transparent-conductive-paint.html exists, but I've no idea how good it is or whether it's available in small quantities. I think it's based on conductive oxide nanoparticles.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any transparent conductive paints.  Have you considered using a piece of metal foil (possibly copper roofing foil from a Home Depot or Lowes) with a piece of veneer adhered to it.  The capacitive touch sense should still work through the veneer.

You can get all kinds of veneers at Woodcraft if you have a store local to you.

[Link to Veneers at Woodcraft](http://www.woodcraft.com/search2/search.aspx?query=veneer)

Comment: yes, but I want to have a rough surface and veneer is just too smooth. Thanks for the input though. Appreciate it.

Comment: You should be able to get the capacitive sensing working up to about 1/2 inch.  You could look at using RF sensing if you need longer distances.  This should allow you to cut a 1/4 thickness of wood.

Comment: @rfs The "veneer" can be as thick as you wish it to be. 1/4 inch should be fine.